# Combining two SELECT queries from same table but different WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named WORKOUTS having column named "install_time" and "local_id". Both are having column type integer. They are UNIQUE keys .I have written two queries like below :

```
SELECT * from workouts where install_time = 123456 and local_id > 5

SELECT * from workouts where install_time = 987643 and local_id > 19
```

Now I wanted to combine both these queries and one where clause to handle this condition but can't find a way for it.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT * from workouts where install_time = 123456 and local_id > 5 and date = xyz
SELECT * from workouts where install_time = 987643 and local_id > 19 and date = xyz
```

Comment: Did you tried using the `OR` condition in between the two conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by **"combine both these queries"**. If you want a result set where the results of both the above queries are returned, you can try the `OR` operator. The following assumes that the `date` field is the same for both the `local_id`s.

```
SELECT * FROM workouts
WHERE date = xyz
AND (
   (install_time = 123456 AND local_id > 5)
   OR (install_time = 987643 AND local_id > 19)
);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * 
FROM workouts 
WHERE 
    (install_time = 123456 AND local_id > 5 AND date = xyz)
    OR 
    (install_time = 987643 AND local_id > 19 AND date = xyz)
```

Also be careful when using the OR keyword. You have to put your parenthesis carefully.

Here is more info on the subject http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

```
SELECT * 
FROM workouts 
WHERE 
    date = xyz
    AND (
      (install_time = 123456 AND local_id > 5)
      OR 
      (install_time = 987643 AND local_id > 19)
    )
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I forgot to mention the date field.

Comment: Yes you can. If the date is same in both conditions you can extract it upfront. But as I said you have to be careful with the parenthesis.

Comment: Although this is not Postgre related you can check this for logical operator precedence -> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The first query is correct, but the one using IN would not render the same values, especially in this case where the comparison with local_id is `>` and not `=`. If the comparison were `=`, IN would still not render the same values (because of alternative combinations), however in PostgreSQL, though, the `IN` operator can work for composite values, which could come in handy: `WHERE (install_time, local_id) IN ((123456, 5), (987654, 19)) and date = xyz`, but the question was for >5 and >19, so it is not applicable here.

Comment: My bad, did not noticed it's >

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * from workouts where install_time = 123456 and local_id > 5 and date = xyz
Union
SELECT * from workouts where install_time = 987643 and local_id > 19 and date = xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply done as

```
SELECT * from workout where date=xyz and ((install_time = 123456 and local_id > 5) or (install_time = 987643  and local_id> 19))
```